# Using Heroku's Free Domain

Tags: heroku, domain-name

I want to use the domain Heroku is hosting my Rails app on. It is something along the lines of http://quiet-waters-7769.herokuapp.com. Can I make this viewable in sites like google? Even if I search for an exact string within my page, google doesn't return my site. It seems like all Heroku domains are unlisted. Is this something I can change in my Heroku settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `robots.txt` and all your meta tags, and make sure you're not telling google to NOT index your site.

- [Using meta tags to block access to your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en)
- [Using robots to block google indexing](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Also, you have to give google time, and a reason to index your site. Just because you have a website, doesn't mean Google will index all your pages.

herokuapp.com domains get indexed fine.

https://www.google.com/#q=site:herokuapp.com